# JsonValueProvider throwing error from MVC App

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

We started seeing this in our log, any idea where to start looking for the problem? There is nothing in the call stack to help us get started.

```
    Message :An item with the same key has already been added. at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource) at 
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean 
add) at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Add(TKey key, TValue value) at 
System.Web.Mvc.JsonValueProviderFactory.EntryLimitedDictionary.Add(String key, 
Object value) at 
System.Web.Mvc.JsonValueProviderFactory.AddToBackingStore(EntryLimitedDictionary
backingStore, String prefix, Object value) at 
System.Web.Mvc.JsonValueProviderFactory.AddToBackingStore(EntryLimitedDictionary
backingStore, String prefix, Object value) at 
System.Web.Mvc.JsonValueProviderFactory.AddToBackingStore(EntryLimitedDictionary backingStore, String prefix, Object value) at 
System.Web.Mvc.JsonValueProviderFactory.AddToBackingStore(EntryLimitedDictionary backingStore, String prefix, Object value) at 
System.Web.Mvc.JsonValueProviderFactory.AddToBackingStore(EntryLimitedDictionary backingStore, String prefix, Object value) at 
System.Web.Mvc.JsonValueProviderFactory.AddToBackingStore(EntryLimitedDictionary backingStore, String prefix, Object value) at 
System.Web.Mvc.JsonValueProviderFactory.AddToBackingStore(EntryLimitedDictionary backingStore, String prefix, Object value) at 
System.Web.Mvc.JsonValueProviderFactory.GetValueProvider(ControllerContext controllerContext) at System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderFactoryCollection.<>c__DisplayClassc.<GetValueProvider>b__7(ValueProviderFactory factory) at 
System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() at 
System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() at 
System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) at 
System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source) at 
System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderFactoryCollection.GetValueProvider(ControllerContext controllerContext) at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.get_ValueProvider() at 
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor) at 
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValues(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass25.
<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) at 
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) at 
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.BeginInvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName, AsyncCallback callback, Object 
state) at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__17(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) at 
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) at 
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, Object state) at 
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) at 
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) at 
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) at 
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__2(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) at 
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) at 
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) at 
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) at 
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) at 
System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Comment: `JsonValueProviderFactory` is called by the `DefaultModelBinder` to convert json to a dictionary that can be used for binding to your model. Do you know which controller method (and the associated ajax call) that tis is occurring in? Best guess is that is some invalid json.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks Stephen. We have a couple of places where we expect JSON. Any idea why there is nothing in the callstack into our app? or any idea if we can capture at this stage the controller that is called?

Comment: I would have expected to see something in the call stack indicating the controller/action method so I'm a bit puzzled.

Comment: One possible cause of this error would be if your json contained 2 properties that were the same name but different case - e.g. `{ name: 'abc', NAME: 'xyz' }`

Comment: @StephenMuecke we have a lot of webhooks callback, thus we dont control the JSON we get. What we are missing is really a way to catch where this is coming from, then see what is the faulty JSON.

Comment: @StephenMuecke We have used ELMAH and that helped us find where the request is coming from and to which controller method. Just putting this comment if someone has the same issue in the future. How to fix this is a different story :-D

Comment: As I noted in previously, the most likely cause is a json object containing 2 properties with the same name so that would need to fixed. If you cannot control the structure, probably the only option would be to create a custom `ModelBinder` that uses a custom `ValueProvider` that checks for duplicate keys before adding it to the dictionary

Comment: @StephenMuecke any example on how to do this? we can't really control the JSON, it is coming as date through a webhook callback.

Comment: I have a simple example that I think could be adapted, but cant access it until tomorrow. Will either comment or add an answer then.

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When your controller method receives json, the `DefaultModelBinder` uses the `JsonValueProviderFactory`, which uses `JavaScriptSerializer` to deserialize the json string and adds the name/value pairs to a dictionary which is passed to the `DictionaryValueProvider` which in turn provides the values for binding.

Your error is caused because your json contains an object with duplicate property names, for example `{ name: someValue, NAME: anotherValue }` so once `name: someValue` has been added to the dictionary, adding `NAME: anotherValue` throws an exception because of the duplicate (case-insensitive) key. This makes sense because a model cannot include 2 properties with the same name.

While the best solution will be to track down and correct the source of the *'invalid'* json, you can write your own `ValueProvideFactory` to bind only the first value and ignore subsequent values with the same key. To save reinventing the wheel use the following steps:

1. Copy the source code of the [JsonValueProviderFactory.cs source
   code](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/JsonValueProviderFactory.cs) into your project
2. Rename the namespace (say `yourProject.ValueProviderFactories`) and
   add a `using System.Web.Mvc;` statement
3. Rename the class (say `InvalidJsonValueProviderFactory`)
4. Modify the following code inside the `private class EntryLimitedDictionary`

   ```
   public void Add(string key, object value)
   {
       if (++_itemCount > _maximumDepth)
       {
           // throw new InvalidOperationException(MvcResources.JsonValueProviderFactory_RequestTooLarge);
       }
       // Add the following if block
       if (_innerDictionary.ContainsKey(key))
       {
           return;
       }
       _innerDictionary.Add(key, value);
   }
   ```
5. Add the following to your `global.asax.cs` file

   ```
   ValueProviderFactories.Factories.Insert(0, new yourProject.ValueProviderFactories.InvalidJsonValueProviderFactory());
   ```

Note that it needs to be added first because the `JsonValueProviderFactory` has already been added to the collection of factories.

This will prevent your exception, but of course means the duplicate property will be throw away. If its important that you get that duplicate, then you could consider more modifications to create a new dictionary entry with a different unique key containing indexers, for example

```
private int _index = 0;
....
if (_innerDictionary.ContainsKey(key))
{
    string invalidKey = string.Format("duplicates[{0}]", _index++);
    string invalidValue = string.Format("{0}|{1}", key, value);
    _innerDictionary.Add(invalidKey, invalidValue);
    return;
}
```

where `index` would start at zero and be incremented each time. Then you could add an additional parameter in the method `string[] duplicates` which would be populated with the duplicate values. At the very least it would aid in debugging the source of the problem.

Comment: Side note: In the code above, I commented out `throw new InvalidOperationException(...)`. Since it should be included, you will need to track down the relevant error message from the [MvcResources.resx source code](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Properties/MvcResources.resx) and add to you project (or just hard code it)

Comment: thanks a lot. We found the root of the problem. We install the webhook on both the Main app, and we have a virtual app, and apparently they run in the same AppPool.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but note....The commented out code is bad as it helps stop denial of service attacks. I assume it is commented out because you can't access the MVCResources.resx, but that is just to get the error description, which is: "The JSON request was too large to be deserialized." So just replace the `MvcResources.JsonValueProviderFactory_RequestTooLarge` with the string equivalent" `"The JSON request was too large to be deserialized."`

Answer (score 0):

I guess issue is when you insert new same key value in Dictionary, that time you are not going to check Key is exist or not, so when you insert already exist key this issue will occur. Simple solution is just check key exist or not before going to insert.

```
// Create Dictionary with two key value pairs.
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>()
{
    {"mac", 1000},
    {"windows", 500}
};

// Use ContainsKey method. To check Linux is exist or not
if (dictionary.ContainsKey("linux") == false)
{
    dictionary.Add("linux",300);         
} else
{
    Console.WriteLine("linux is already Exist");
}
```

In Above Example mac,window and linux are key of directory. directory have one rule it will never add again exist key. so you have to check before add.

Comment: Thanks. However not sure what those keys are, in the Callstack there is nothing helping me to find where problem.

Comment: The error is being thrown by a private method in [JsonValueProviderFactory.cs](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/JsonValueProviderFactory.cs) source code of MVC - OP cannot modify it

Comment: Nivar, I totally understand the error message, that is not the problem. My problem is how to find out which controller is throwing the error message.

Comment: Yes, when you create object of JsonValueProviderFactory class in controller that time you are assigning a Directory. that throwing the error.