# IIS Or Asp.Net duplicate key issues

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, shopify, webhooks

I asked a question about this last week, and thought it was answered, but not really.

Here is the setup:

- Our App listens to a webhook from a Shopify
- Shopify sends some JSON, and we validated that the JSON has no duplicates
- However the webhook fires very often (that's the only suspicious things we see)
- We get the error below even before getting to our code

  [image: An Item with the same key has already been added]
  The question is: is there a setting in IIS that is causing this? Anything with MVC?

Comment: Do you have `Dictionary` as an argument of and action?

Comment: @IvanGritsenko The Callbacks receive as JSON, and we made sure it doesn't have duplicates.

Comment: @MBen, There is only one possible explanation for that error and that is that you do have duplicate data. Did try the custom `JsonValueProviderFactor` I gave you in the [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35981215/jsonvalueprovider-throwing-error-from-mvc-app) which does prevent this error being thrown.

Comment: @StephenMuecke This time I validated that the JSON has no duplicates, and we can import it separately without any issues. I believe the issue is that Shopify sends a lot of notification (we saw duplicates in the DB as well)

Comment: If it's happening before it hits your code it is most likely something in MVC.  The stacktrace seems to indicate a duplicate value provider for JSON data.  Are you registering a custom provider for application/json content?

Comment: @Brad Not really, using out of the box. Any option we can set?Again, if we import the order, it works, and has no duplicates